# grep search with white space characters

Tags: bash, grep

I have structure

```
struct my_struct_t {
 ......
 .......
};
```

I'm trying to use grep to print lines that match the structure definition: the pattern I'm searching is the keyword 'struct' and the open  brace '{'.

```
   grep struct"\s"."\s"{
```

But I does not work, how do I get the lines matching the structure pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special character is needed for spaces, so long as you wrap your pattern in single quotes:

```
grep '^struct [[:alnum:]_]\+ {$' myfile.c
```

This will:

1. Ensure that `struct` is at the very beginning of the line, followed by a single space
2. Look for the alphanumeric (and underscore) name of the `struct`
3. Ensure that a single space and `{` are at the end of the line

Given your example, this will output the following:

```
struct my_struct_t {
```